# GitLab project export error (tar filtered error)

Tags: export, gitlab, size

Recently I had a specific problem with exporting project from Gitlab, this is what I  got on my mail from GitLab after clicked on export button:

*Project Test_Project couldn't be exported.
The errors we encountered were:
tar: [FILTERED] Cannot open: No such file or directory tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Unable to save [FILTERED] into [FILTERED]*

Could it happen because of size of the repo (10GB)?

Thanks for the answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues open in GitLab that reference imports timing out due to repo size, so that's probably your problem. There are some suggestions in the comments of this issue that might help you! https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/46495

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution for us, because we have problem with exporting project from gitlab.com not importing and not from the own server instance.